Is there any solution to resolve write permission issue in /(slash) directory?
I have a Dockerfile on Alpine base image as 3.13, in that I installed and ran a moshell application and it is working fine but am getting write permission issue in other alpine versions like below
You do not have write permission in /tmp/; Exiting....
I tried installing and running moshell on alpine image with version 3.13, now I want to do the same in other alpine versions but the problem is I am getting write permission issue.
